# i am trying to write python pandas dataframe but it showing errors

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write python pandas dataframe but it showing errors

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-48ebb3034353> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 s=pd.series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
      3 
      4 print(s)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    242         return _SparseArray
    243 
--> 244     raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
    245 
    246 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series'
```

​

Comment: [pd.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series) is capital `S`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
s=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Your `s` in `series` should be uppercase --- > `pd.Series`.

Comment: @SivaKumarYarramsetti please tick if it’s correct